# How can I update/recalculate the floating? Keywords: position:sticky, float, text overlap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can you, while scrolling, let an HTML element with `position:sticky` float through several long texts?

```js
var long_text = 'Scroll me! You can see that the red box covers the long text. How can I recalculate the floating? … Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.'
var liste = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

for (key in liste){
    $('#text').append(`<li>${liste[key]} -- ${long_text}</li>`);
}
```

```css
#topright {
    background-color:red;
    float:right;
    height:5em;
    position:sticky;
    top:0em;
    width:5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="parent">
    <div id="topright"></div>
    <ul id="text"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Per [this w3schools article](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp), `position:sticky` toggles the element between `position:relative` and `position:fixed`. A fixed element is not going to allow text to wrap, because it is out of the main position flow.

You could do this with JavaScript, but it'll be clunky.

Comment: Thank you. I'll take care of it. It upsets me. Why don't the W3C, the browser manufacturers or anyone else get it right? That would be something I would solve first. Technically, that's not a problem, is it?